# Kotlin App open activity 2 with button CRASH

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

so this is the error in the logcat however when i try to declare "CreateNoteFragment" in the manifest only the .MainActivity & .SplashScreen appear and does not let me declare the .CreateNoteFragment

my CreateNoteFragment also references "BaseFragment" activity as such below error.
my button click code is in .MainActivity the only place it wont break and here is the code for that below. when click it crashes the app any help would be appreciated

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.moradi.moradinotespro/com.moradi.moradinotespro.CreateNoteFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

```
class CreateNoteFragment : BaseFragment() {

  //Button Click Create Note
        fabBtnCreateNote == findViewById(R.id.fabBtnCreateNote)

        fabBtnCreateNote.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, CreateNoteFragment::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

        replaceFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(), true)
    }
```

manifest included

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.moradi.moradinotespro">

    <!-- Permissions
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
            <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Splash

```
class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var handler: Handler
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)

        handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed({
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        },  2000)  // delaying for 2 sec till open
        }
    }
```

CreateNoteFragment Activity

```
class CreateNoteFragment : BaseFragment() {
    var currentDate:String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_note, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
            CreateNoteFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/m/yyyy hh:m:ss")
        currentDate = sdf.format(Date())

        tvDateTime.text = currentDate

        imgDone.setOnClickListener {
            //Save Note
            saveNote()
        }

        imgBack.setOnClickListener {
            replaceFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(),  false)
        }
    }
    private fun saveNote() {
        if (etNoteTitle.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Title Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (etNoteSubTitle.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "SubTitle Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        if (etNoteDesc.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Note Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }



        launch {
        val notes = Notes()
            notes.title = etNoteTitle.text.toString()
            notes.subTitle = etNoteSubTitle.text.toString()
            notes.noteText = etNoteDesc.text.toString()
            notes.dateTime = currentDate
            context?.let {
            NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().insertNotes(notes)
                etNoteTitle.setText("")
                etNoteSubTitle.setText("")
                etNoteDesc.setText("")
            }

        }
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, istransition: Boolean) {
        val fragmentTransition = activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        if (istransition) {
            fragmentTransition.setCustomAnimations(
                android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left
            )
        }
        fragmentTransition.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
    }
}
```

Comment: check whether MainActivity is defined in manifest or not

Comment: it is that does not fix the issue

Comment: can you show splashscreen code, if you are going to mainactivity from splash

Comment: well its complicated i suppose im trying to go to CreateNoteFragment Activity but in the manifest it will not let me add the CreateNoteFragment  to the manifest only the Splash and Main but the from splash it goes to home fragment then when i click add note button to goto CreateNoteFragment  it crashes i updated the post with more code

Comment: you cant add fragment in Manifest

Comment: Thats just the name of it its a class file just like main and splash screen but it dont appear because all the things i search say createnotefragment needs added to manifest to prevent crashing

Comment: no, you cant as you are extending it with basefragment

Comment: well thats the class file that contains what i need behind the button that causes crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here:

```
fabBtnCreateNote.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, CreateNoteFragment::class.java) 
            startActivity(intent)

        }
```

CreateNoteFragment is not an Activity, so you cannot start it as an activity

First, you need to create main_activity.xml file and sepecific id of Framelayout with "frame_layout" like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Then, change set content view for MainActivity with this line:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
}
```

You need to replace from HomeFragment to CreateNoteFragment:

```
    fabBtnCreateNote.setOnClickListener {
        val newFragment = CreateNoteFragment.newInstance()
        activity?.let {activity->
            val transaction = activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
           transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment,CreateNoteFragment::class.simpleName);
        // Commit the transaction
           transaction.commit();  
      }
}
```

Your CreateNoteFragment was added to back stack, so you just call onBackPress() when back button clicked:
Change your code:

```
imgBack.setOnClickListener {
        activity.onBackPress()
    }
```

Comment: when i changethe code however it says Unresolved reference: newFragment newFragment = new CreateNoteFragment(); and Unresolved reference: FragmentTransaction

Comment: I just updated my answer with Kotlin version, hope it could solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it is still crashing with the updated code this is very odd

Comment: but i think it is to do with something else because the logcat now shows this java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup ugh

Comment: show your new code and main_activity.xml code please!

Comment: change this line
`transaction.replace(R.id.fabBtnCreateNote, newFragment,CreateNoteFragment::class.simpleName);` to `transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, newFragment,CreateNoteFragment::class.simpleName)`

Comment: did, still nothing hmm, `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900ab (com.moradi.moradinotespro:id/frame_layout) for fragment CreateNoteFragment{b35ae20 (eb68343b-4393-48d0-9508-ecab4c4bc883) id=0x7f0900ab CreateNoteFragment}
`

Comment: did you change this line?
`imgBack.setOnClickListener { replaceFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(),  false) }` to `imgBack.setOnClickListener {  activity?.onBackPress()}`

Comment: Unresolved reference: onBackPress https://pastebin.com/05TkdYPX

Comment: srr, it should be activity?.onBackPressed()

Comment: ok it was `imgBack.setOnClickListener { activity?.onBackPressed() ` but still crashes, `No view found for id 0x7f0900ab` i know this is a pain i do appreciate you helping me try to solve it hmmm wonder what now

Comment: I read your code from your github repository. Try to remove those lines inside MainActiviy.kt:
`    //Button Click Create Note
        fabBtnCreateNote == findViewById(R.id.fabBtnCreateNote)

        fabBtnCreateNote.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, CreateNoteFragment::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }`

Comment: those are all removed i just dident push the updated code you gave me i just updated that code if you wanted to refresh that

Comment: don't forget to commit the transaction : 
fragmentTransition.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName).commit()

Comment: remove those code in MainActivity.kt:
 ` fabBtnCreateNote.setOnClickListener {
            val newFragment = CreateNoteFragment.newInstance()
            this.let { activity->
                val transaction = activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, newFragment,CreateNoteFragment::class.simpleName)
      // Commit the transaction transaction.commit(); }}
`

Comment: or you can download source code here: https://gofile.io/d/qtrWb6

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I really appreciate all your help